Buenas, tengo un problema al crear imagenes haciendo una captura de unos paneles de un formulario
El código que uso es este:
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        tabControl1.SelectedTab = pestañas[i];
        if (File.Exists(Application.StartupPath + "\\Planning\\" + meses[i] + ".bmp"))
            Delete(Application.StartupPath + "\\Planning\\" + meses[i] + ".bmp");    
            bitmap = new Bitmap(paneles[i].Width, paneles[i].Height);    
            paneles[i].DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, paneles[i].Width, paneles[i].Height));    
                // Ajustar el tamaño del bitmap al tamaño de la página    
            bitmap = ResizeBitmap(bitmap, (int)document.PageSize.Width - 40, (int)document.PageSize.Height - 14);    
            bitmap.Save(Application.StartupPath + "\\Planning\\" + meses[i] + ".bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);    
                // Crear una instancia de la imagen en el documento PDF    
            iTextSharp.text.Image imagen1 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bitmap, ImageFormat.Bmp);    
                // Agregar una nueva página al documento PDF    
            document.NewPage();    
                // Añadir la imagen al documento PDF    
            document.Add(imagen1); 
        }    
            // Cerrar el documento PDF    
        document.Close();
}

El error me aparece en esta línea, solo en el panel 12 del bucle:
paneles[i].DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, paneles[i].Width, paneles[i].Height));

El bitmap existe y el ancho y alto del panel es también correcto.
El resto lo genera correctamente.
Si en el bucle empiezo desde el valor 1, me genera la imagen de el panel 12.
No se si es problema de tema de recursos, memoria etc.
Muchas gracias.

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! que error?

el error que me aparece es el siguiente:
System.ArgumentException: 'El parámetro no es válido.'
He probado a realizar el proceso manualmente de 1 en 1 y al llegar al panel 12 me sigue dando ese mismo error,
los parámetros de ancho y alto son válidos, no entiendo muy bien a que se debe el error, como comentaba no se si algún tema de recursos.
Por si sirve de ayuda el tamaño de cada panel es :   1357 ancho; 710 alto
Muchas gracias, un saludo y disculpas, soy nuevo por estos lares.

Y perdiste el usuario con el que hiciste la pregunta??? Vamos a hacer una cosa.. hace una pregunta nueva. que incluya toda la informacion, porque sigue estando incompleta.. que linea tira ese error??? voy a borrar esta pregunta (porque perdiste la cuenta) y obviamente esta respuesta que no es una respuesta...
